# Order and limit number of results shown by JavaScript search bar

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple search bar and a somewhat large JSON file with `name, x, y` values for each entry. Given some (x, y) values (e.g.: `1.2 0.5`) the JavaScript search bar shows cards that are within a fixed distance of 1 to that value.

This works but I need to:

1. Limit the number of results to a maximum (say 10) so that there won't be hundreds or more results shown at the same time
2. Order the results by minimum distance to the (x, y) value searched

Any help will be much appreciated

```js
const userCardTemplate = document.querySelector("[data-user-template]")
const userCardContainer = document.querySelector("[data-user-cards-container]")
const searchInput = document.querySelector("[data-search]")

let users = []

searchInput.addEventListener("input", e => {
  const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
  const xy = value.split(' ')
  users.forEach(user => {
  if (parseFloat(value.length) < 4) {
  user.element.classList.toggle("hide", true)
} else {
    var distance = Math.sqrt(
      Math.pow(parseFloat(xy[0]) - parseFloat(user.x), 2) +
      Math.pow(parseFloat(xy[1]) - parseFloat(user.y), 2))
    const isVisible = distance <= 1
  user.element.classList.toggle("hide", !isVisible)
}
  })
})

fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ucc23/ucc/main/test.json")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
users = data.map(user => {
  const card = userCardTemplate.content.cloneNode(true).children[0]
  const header = card.querySelector("[data-header]")
  const body = card.querySelector("[data-body]")
  header.textContent = user.name
  card.classList.add('hide')
  userCardContainer.append(card)
  return {
    name: user.name,
    x: user.x,
    y: user.y,
    element: card
  }
})
  })
```

```css
.user-cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  gap: .25rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: .5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.card > .header {
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <input type="search" id="search" data-search>
  </div>
  <div class="user-cards" data-user-cards-container></div>
  <template data-user-template>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="header" data-header></div>
    </div>
  </template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my answer, I'm not appending the cards on the loading of the json file. This makes it load faster plus allows easy sorting later on.

I created a new array called results, this will store the matching results. On input, I empty the results and empty the html of the card container, that way the results will always be up to date. Then I append the user with it's distance to the results array.

After that I sort the array based on the distance, then I slice the array to the first N results in this case I have it set to 10.

After that I simply loop through the results and append them to the card container element.

Also, I moved the input length if statement outside of the loop, no need to re run it for every user.

```js
const userCardTemplate = document.querySelector("[data-user-template]")
const userCardContainer = document.querySelector("[data-user-cards-container]")
const searchInput = document.querySelector("[data-search]")

let users = []
let results = []
searchInput.addEventListener("input", e => {
  results = []; //quickly empty array
  userCardContainer.innerHTML = "";
  const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
  const xy = value.split(' ')
  if (parseFloat(value.length) >= 4) {
    users.forEach(user => {

      var distance = Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(parseFloat(xy[0]) - parseFloat(user.x), 2) +
        Math.pow(parseFloat(xy[1]) - parseFloat(user.y), 2))
    if(distance <= 1){
      user.distance = distance
      results.push(
        user
      );
     }

    })

  }

  results.sort((a, b) => a.distance - b.distance)
  
  results = results.slice(0,10)
  
  results.forEach((u) => {
    userCardContainer.append(u.element);
  });

  
})

fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ucc23/ucc/main/test.json")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    users = data.map(user => {
      const card = userCardTemplate.content.cloneNode(true).children[0]
      const header = card.querySelector("[data-header]")
      header.textContent = user.name
      return {
        name: user.name,
        x: user.x,
        y: user.y,
        element: card
      }
    })
  })
```

```css
.user-cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  gap: .25rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: .5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.card>.header {
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-wrapper">
  <input type="search" id="search" data-search>
</div>
<div class="user-cards" data-user-cards-container></div>
<template data-user-template>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="header" data-header></div>
    </div>
  </template>
```

Comment: Amazing answer thank you very much! Is it possible that your answer even fixed an **Avoid an excessive DOM size** warning I was getting with the old code?

Comment: @Gabriel it probably did fix that problem as my answer only adds a max of 10 cards to the DOM at a time (or whatever you limit the array to).

Answer (score 0):

I shortened the input data a little to make it clearer:

```js
const data = [
  {
   "name": "mwsc4688",
   "x": 0.5809138064,
   "y": 0.3204712061
  },
  {
   "name": "mwsc5684",
   "x": 0.831380058,
   "y": 0.334242817
  },
  {
   "name": "mwsc5692",
   "x": 0.1744799133,
   "y": 0.2460810205
  },
  {
   "name": "mwsc4005",
   "x": 0.9892221203,
   "y": 0.8656343945
  },
  {
   "name": "mwsc4176",
   "x": 0.2958017735,
   "y": 0.6074523398
  },
  {
   "name": "eso00806",
   "x": 0.3700941722,
   "y": 0.7938580839
  },
  {
   "name": "mwsc4219",
   "x": 0.0444884369,
   "y": 0.6772385082
  },
  {
   "name": "mwsc5575",
   "x": 0.0239875802,
   "y": 0.5067098227
  },
];

function search(x, y, distance = 1, count = 10){
  return data.filter(item => Math.abs(x - item.x) <= distance && Math.abs(y - item.y) <= distance)
    .sort((a, b) => (b.x + b.y - distance) - (a.x + a.y - distance))
    .slice(0, count);
}

console.log(search(1.2, .5, 1, 6));
```